# How to avoid users to download, extract or edit an image in my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Android application where I want to sell with Google In-app purchase some images to be displayed on my users' avatar profile. I get those images from a website which allow this as long as users can't download, extract or edit the image to protect intellectual property.

So I'm thinking about storing these images in a website image storage and then store the url to the image on Firestore database. Once the user buy my image (he buy in fact the url to the image), a boolean value is set to true and then he can query the url and the image is retrieved with Android Coil library.
So I think to disable the Coil cache data to not permit the user to retrieve the image in the cache.

My question is how to avoid users to find my Url if they retro enginering the app because the url will conduct to the image that they can download and so how to properly avoid users to download, edit or extract the image using Coil or glide librairies for example.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I found that Glide cache data is not accessible to the user. So I will store image in Firebase Storage, download URL and put this url to Glide. Then, as Glide fetch data first from cache, it will not cost me so much.